# Check if date is less than another in SQL and VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have 2 SQL tables (A & B) with dates in the format DD/MM/YYYY and time, for example 01/03/2012 00:00:00. In my VB.net application I am looking to count the number of records in table A which have a date less than the one in table B. I have no problem getting the dates from the database. I have extracted the date in table B and stored this in the program. Im just not sure how to compare the dates within the SQL query.

In short what I am trying to do is:

```
"select count(records) as totalRecords from table A where date < " & dateBvariable & ""
```

Any Help appreciated

Comment: What you have is fine - *assuming* that `dateBvariable` is in fact, a date. You probably need single-quotes though. Although you're using the "less than" symbol it's clearer to refer to dates as "earlier than".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
"select * from lk.media_months where begin_on < cast('" & dateVarialbe & "' as DATETIME)"
```

Comment: had to change this slightly but pointed me in the right direction thanks. Used this in the end up:  CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & Format(date(i), "yyyy-MM-dd") & " 00:00:00', 102))

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance it'll work if you pass the date as a string in `'` quotes:

```
where date < '" & dateBvariable & "'"
```

Or format it to the ODBC standard:

```
where date < '" & dateBvariable.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "'"
```

Even better is to pass a parameter:

```
where date < @par1
```

And add the parameter to the `SqlCommand`:

```
command.AddWithValue "@par1", dateBvariable
```

Comment: tried all of these but still no luck. Going to try the conversion within the SQL now to see if I have any luck. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Try using a parameter to set the date. E.g.:

```
Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("select count(records) as totalRecords from tableA where dateField < @DateParam")

sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateParam", DateTime.Today)
```